# Julia: Can isposdef() be used to determine if a matrix can be factored by Cholesky decomposition?

Tags: math, matrix, julia

I am trying to use isposdef() in Julia as a way to test a priori whether a matrix can be factored by the cholesky decomposition.

It looks like isposdef does not always work. Am I using it incorrectly?

Example:

```
D = [5, 8]
V = [1 2; 3 4]
A = V*diagm(D)*inv(V)
println(eig(A))
println(isposdef(A))
```

Here I create a matrix A with positive eigenvalues given in D. We see that eig(A) agrees they are positive. Isposdef(), however, returns false. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: The concept of "positive definite" applies to *symmetric* (or Hermitian) matrices.  Your matrix `A` is not symmetric.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. It is not sufficient that the eigenvalues be positive. Weird. In class the professors always state "symmetric positive definite" when apparently "positive definite" would be enough.

Comment: Well, the definition (v*A*v^T > 0 for all nonzero v) could still be applied to an arbitrary square real matrix, but (a) the theorem about positive eigenvalues is no longer true in that generality, and (b) the extended definition isn't that interesting: a general square matrix A is positive definite if and only if its symmetric part ((A + A^T) / 2) is positive definite.  But in this generalized sense (which may be what Julia is using), your matrix is *not* positive definite - the eigenvalues of the symmetric part are 17.1... and -4.1...  So Julia is giving the correct result here.

Comment: Update: from testing and looking at the source, Julia's `isposdef` includes an explicit test for symmetry.

Comment: What is the standard protocol here? Can I 'close' my question somehow since it was incorrect/answered?

Comment: I think it's a fine question (and clearly at least two other people do too, judging by the upvotes); I don't see any particular reason to delete it.  I should really have taken the time to put my comments into an answer, and that may yet happen if no-one else beats me to it.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: please do add an answer if you have a chance. What you have written is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a matrix A has cholesky decomposition, then A can be written as A=LL^T( which is feasible if A=QDQ^T and eigen values are all positive,  where L=QD^0.5) which implies that the matrix should be positive-definite(this subsumes the symmetricity also).

From your example, for the matrix A = V*D*inv(V), the matrix of eigen vectors V, you chose is not Orthonormal. So you cant go from A = V*D*inv(V) to the form above for cholesky decomposition.

As to your main question, since positive definiteness is necessary and sufficient condition for cholesky decomposition to exist, isposdef() can be used to check if a cholesky decomposition exists.

PS: Please look at Mark Dickinson's comments under the question for a more general discussion.